# Expand list columns with variable length into rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a input dataframe containing multiple list columns with unequal number of elements with in the list. I need to expand all the list columns into rows so that each bin has the corresponding value in the same row.

code for generating the df:

```
df_dict = {'vin':['VIN123','VIN123','VIN123','VIN234','VIN345'],
          'date':['01-22-2022','01-23-2022','01-23-2022','01-23-2022','01-22-2022'],
          'celltype':['A','A','B','A','B'],
          'soc_bins':[['0-10','10-20','50-80','85-90','100-150','150-170'],['0-10','10-20','50-80','85-90','100-150','150-170'],['0-10','10-20','50-80','85-90','100-150','150-170'],['0-10','10-20','50-80','85-90','100-150','150-170'],['0-10','10-20','50-80','85-90','100-150','150-170']],
          'soc_value': [[10,300,85,20,5,0],[20,400,125,670,5,7],[20,500,55,60,9,9],[40,300,65,90,1,0],[20,700,35,50,2,0]],
          'temp_bins':[['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f']],
          'temp_value':[[1,2,3],[4,3,4],[5,3,5],[6,900,7],[3,600,9]],
          'temp_bins':[['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f'],['50f-55f','60f-70f','90f-110f']]}
```

Input_df:
[image]

Output_df:

| vin | date | celltype | soc_bins | soc_value | temp_bins | temp_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VIN123 | 01-22-2022 | A | 0-10 | 10 | 50f-55f | 1 |
| VIN123 | 01-22-2022 | A | 10-20 | 300 | 60f-70f | 2 |

In short, each value in the soc_value column corresponds to the corresponding bin in the soc_bin column and same goes for the temp columns.

Few problems I encountered using the explode method or similar methods is:

1. The number of bins in soc_bins (5) and temp_bins (3) are not equal.
2. Also, there might be a same value for two bins (ex: 3rd row, soc_value contains two values as 9) so when I first expand the soc_value column there is no way for the explode fucntion to identify the two rows as different and hence i am getting an error "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"
3. There are a lot many columns that has to be manipulated in the same way.
4. Can use `df.set_index('date','vin','celltype').apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index()` but i am getting NaN's in the indexed columns.
   To fill the NaN's I can use the .ffill() but I am unable to distinguish between original null values.
   Also, in this method if some of indexes are null's i'm getting an error "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Current output:
[image]

**Required output**: I need the output similar to my current output but without the null values. I could use .ffill() to fill the null values, but then i am unable to differentiate the actual null values vs the the ones created from the df.set_index().

Comment: What is your wanted end df?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a row_number to the df before exploding it into columns has solved the "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!" issue.

`df['row_number'] = np.arange(len(df))`

`df.set_index('date','vin','celltype').apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index()`